# UI flickering when selecting property in a Property grid control

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I have a property grid and a combo box, Based on the value of the combo box i change the propertygrid.SelectedItem and refresh the property grid.
The problem is that whenever i select a value to edit the whole screen starts flickering like it's repainting or redrawing. This only happens when i select a property on the property grid, it goes away when i go to another screen and comeback. I have not written any redraw functions on click events.

[edit1]I've added a code snippet of combo box selected item change

```
if (this.comboBoxHomerSelectSettings.SelectedItem.ToString() == "AppSettings")
            {
                this.comboBoxHomerSublist.Visible = false;
                this.propertyGridEditSettings.SelectedObject = Settings.SingleInstance.SettingsValues.AppSettings;
            }
            else if (this.comboBoxHomerSelectSettings.SelectedItem.ToString() == "WaferSpecificSettings")
            {
                this.comboBoxHomerSublist.Visible = true;
                this.comboBoxHomerSublist.Items.Clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < Settings.SingleInstance.SettingsValues.WaferSpeicificSettingsList.WaferSpeicificInformationList.Count;i++ )
                {
                    this.comboBoxHomerSublist.Items.Add(Settings.SingleInstance.SettingsValues.WaferSpeicificSettingsList.WaferSpeicificInformationList.ElementAt(i));
                }
                this.comboBoxHomerSublist.SelectedIndex = 0;
                this.propertyGridEditSettings.SelectedObject = this.comboBoxHomerSublist.SelectedItem;
            }
            else if (this.comboBoxHomerSelectSettings.SelectedItem.ToString() == "BinColorMapping")
            {
                this.comboBoxHomerSublist.Visible = true;
                this.comboBoxHomerSublist.Items.Clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < Settings.SingleInstance.SettingsValues.BinColorInfoList.BinColorInformationList.Count; i++)
                {
                    this.comboBoxHomerSublist.Items.Add(Settings.SingleInstance.SettingsValues.BinColorInfoList.BinColorInformationList.ElementAt(i));
                }
                this.comboBoxHomerSublist.SelectedIndex = 0;
                this.propertyGridEditSettings.SelectedObject = this.comboBoxHomerSublist.SelectedItem;
            }
            else if (this.comboBoxHomerSelectSettings.SelectedItem.ToString() == "CommonSettings")
            {
                this.comboBoxHomerSublist.Visible = false;
                this.propertyGridEditSettings.SelectedObject = Settings.SingleInstance.SettingsValues.CommonSettings;
            }
            else if (this.comboBoxHomerSelectSettings.SelectedItem.ToString() == "DOETypeMapping")
            {
                this.comboBoxHomerSublist.Visible = true;
                this.comboBoxHomerSublist.Items.Clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < Settings.SingleInstance.SettingsValues.DOETypeMapingInfoList.DOETypeMapingInformationList.Count; i++)
                {
                    this.comboBoxHomerSublist.Items.Add(Settings.SingleInstance.SettingsValues.DOETypeMapingInfoList.DOETypeMapingInformationList.ElementAt(i));
                }
                this.comboBoxHomerSublist.SelectedIndex = 0;
                this.propertyGridEditSettings.SelectedObject = this.comboBoxHomerSublist.SelectedItem;
            }
            this.propertyGridEditSettings.Refresh();
```

Comment: [mcve] will really help here.

Comment: Without any code our hands are tied.